# How to keep the legend stable in a fieldset in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, fieldset

The legend is not staying in place when I hide and then show elements in the field set.  This works fine on Chome/FF, but not on IE 11.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Test</legend>
<div class='hider'>Hide this</div>
<div>Lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots 
     and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and 
     lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots 
     and lots of content.</div>
</fieldset>
```

JS:

```
function myShow(me)
{
    $(me).unbind();
    $(me).parent().children(':not(.hider)').show();
    $(me).click(function () {
        myHide(me);
    });
}

function myHide(me)
{
    $(me).unbind();
    $(me).parent().children(':not(.hider)').hide();
    $(me).click(function () {
        myShow(me);
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('.hider').click(function () {
        myHide(this);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle that shows it happening on IE 11.
http://jsfiddle.net/etb21zrr/

It works fine if you don't hide the legend, as seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xy9ofu77/

While that can likely work for my immediate need, I would still like to leave this question open to see if there is a way correctly hide and show the legend in IE 11 in case anyone else needs to know (or if the customer ends up not liking changing the header to 'deleted').

Comment: The jsFiddle is hiding the `<legend>` element as well. Is this intended?

Comment: Is [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/5q655xv9/) closer to the desired behaviour?

Comment: Seems like the `<legend>` tag is being set to `display:inline` after it's un-hidden.  For some reason, IE doesn't "like" that.

Comment: @misterManSam In your example, at least in IE 11, the legend now starts off in the incorrect position.

Comment: @elzi Yes, that is the desired result in this case (they are pressing a delete button, and everything in the legend should go away except for an 'undelete' button.  I may try to not hide the legend and instead switch it to say 'Deleted'.  I'll see if that changes anything.